# Pine-script error "No Data" on backtesting

Tags: pine-script

I am getting a "No data" error on the strategy tester on TV when I run my code. I am trying to combine multiple indicators into one strategy and a BUY or SELL order will trigger when all the indicators line up as per the long and short conditions at the end of the code below. Here is my code:

```
//@version=4

strategy(title="Strategy", shorttitle="St", format=format.price, process_orders_on_close=true, precision=2, initial_capital=10000, calc_on_order_fills=false, calc_on_every_tick=true, default_qty_type=strategy.cash, default_qty_value=1000, currency="USD")

// SSL channel

period=input(title="Period", defval=10)
len=input(title="Period", defval=10)
smaHigh=sma(high, len)
smaLow=sma(low, len)
float Hlv = na
Hlv := close > smaHigh ? 1 : close < smaLow ? -1 : Hlv[1]
sslDown = Hlv < 0 ? smaHigh: smaLow
sslUp   = Hlv < 0 ? smaLow : smaHigh

//plot(sslDown, linewidth=2, color=red)
//plot(sslUp, linewidth=2, color=lime)

//Kijun-Sen+

basePeriods = input(26, minval=1, title="Period")
donchian(len) => avg(lowest(len), highest(len))
baseLine = donchian(basePeriods)
//plot(baseLine, color=#991515, title="Kijun-Sen")

//WAE

sensitivity = input(150, title="Sensitivity")
fastLength=input(20, title="FastEMA Length")
slowLength=input(40, title="SlowEMA Length")
channelLength=input(20, title="BB Channel Length")
mult=input(2.0, title="BB Stdev Multiplier")

DEAD_ZONE = nz(rma(tr(true),100)) * 3.7

calc_macd(source, fastLength, slowLength) =>
    fastMA = ema(source, fastLength)
    slowMA = ema(source, slowLength)
    fastMA - slowMA

calc_BBUpper(source, length, mult) => 
    basis = sma(source, length)
    dev = mult * stdev(source, length)
    basis + dev

calc_BBLower(source, length, mult) => 
    basis = sma(source, length)
    dev = mult * stdev(source, length)
    basis - dev

t1 = (calc_macd(close, fastLength, slowLength) - calc_macd(close[1], fastLength, slowLength))*sensitivity
t2 = (calc_macd(close[2], fastLength, slowLength) - calc_macd(close[3], fastLength, slowLength))*sensitivity

e1 = (calc_BBUpper(close, channelLength, mult) - calc_BBLower(close, channelLength, mult))

trendUp = (t1 >= 0) ? t1 : 0
trendDown = (t1 < 0) ? (-1*t1) : 0

//plot(trendUp, style=columns, linewidth=1, color=(trendUp<trendUp[1])?lime:green, transp=45, title="UpTrend")
//plot(trendDown, style=columns, linewidth=1, color=(trendDown<trendDown[1])?orange:red, transp=45, title="DownTrend")
//plot(e1, style=line, linewidth=2, color=#A0522D, title="ExplosionLine")
//plot(DEAD_ZONE, color=blue, linewidth=1, style=cross, title="DeadZoneLine")

//RVGI

len1 = input(10, title="Length", minval=1)
rvi = sum(swma(close-open), len)/sum(swma(high-low),len1)
sig = swma(rvi)
offset = input(0, "Offset", type = input.integer, minval = -500, maxval = 500)
//plot(rvi, color=#008000, title="RVGI", offset = offset)
//plot(sig, color=#FF0000, title="Signal", offset = offset)

//AROON

length = input(14, minval=1)
upper = 100 * (highestbars(high, length+1) + length)/length
lower = 100 * (lowestbars(low, length+1) + length)/length
//plot(upper, "Aroon Up", color=#FF6A00)
//plot(lower, "Aroon Down", color=#0094FF)

//ATR

atrLength = input(14, "ATR Length")
slMultiplier = input(1.5, "SL")
tpMultiplier = input(1, "TP1")

atr = atr(atrLength)

bool long = close > sslUp and close > baseLine and trendUp > e1 and rvi > sig and upper > lower
bool short = close < sslDown and close < baseLine and trendDown > e1 and sig > rvi and lower > upper
//long_exit = upper < lower
//short_exit = lower > upper

if(long)
    strategy.entry("Long", long, 10000, limit = atr*tpMultiplier, stop = atr*slMultiplier)
//strategy.close("Long Exit", long, when = long_exit)
if(short)
    strategy.entry("Short", short, 10000, limit = atr*tpMultiplier, stop = atr*slMultiplier)
//strategy.close("Short Exit", short, when = short_exit)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `stop` parameter in `strategy.entry()` is not allowing entering any position, as it is out of range of the bars prices.

```
strategy.entry("Long", true, 10000, limit = atr*tpMultiplier, stop = atr*slMultiplier)
```

You can add this lines to see value of  `atr*tpMultiplier`:

```
bgcolor(long? color.green:na)
plot(atr*tpMultiplier, color = color.red)
plot(atr*slMultiplier, color = color.green)

bgcolor(short? color.red:na)
```

Change `TP1`, `SL1` parameters in your strategy, e.g:
[image]

Comment: I tried doing exactly as you said, but still getting the same error "No Data"